# Getting unknown property: app\models\AlumnyS2::alumniintegrasi

Tags: php, yii2

I want to display data relation by making a relation between table alumniintegrasi with alumnys2, but when I made it with gridview, there was an error.

it said '

> getting unknown property: app\models\AlumnyS2::alumniintegrasi.

here is the code

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use app\models\AlumniIntegrasi;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\AlumnyS2Search */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Alumny S2s');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="alumny-s2-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Alumny S2'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'NRP',
            //'NamaMahasiswa',

            [
            'attribute' => 'NamaMahasiswa',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->alumniintegrasi->NamaMahasiswa;
            },

            /*'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'orang_ID', ArrayHelper::map(Orang::find()->asArray()->all(), 'ID', 'Nama'),['class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Select Category']),
            */
            ],


            'ProgramStudi',
            'Tanggal_Masuk',
            'Tanggal_Lulus',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

and here is the model

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "alumnys2".
 *
 * @property string $NRP
 * @property string $NamaMahasiswa
 * @property string $ProgramStudi
 * @property string $Tanggal_Masuk
 * @property string $Tanggal_Lulus
 *
 * @property AlumniIntegrasi $nRP
 */
class AlumnyS2 extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'alumnys2';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['NRP', 'NamaMahasiswa'], 'required'],
            [['NRP'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
            [['NamaMahasiswa'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['ProgramStudi'], 'string', 'max' => 5],
            [['Tanggal_Masuk', 'Tanggal_Lulus'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
            [['NRP'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => AlumniIntegrasi::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['NRP' => 'NRP']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'NRP' => Yii::t('app', 'Nrp'),
            'NamaMahasiswa' => Yii::t('app', 'Nama Mahasiswa'),
            'ProgramStudi' => Yii::t('app', 'Program Studi'),
            'Tanggal_Masuk' => Yii::t('app', 'Tanggal  Masuk'),
            'Tanggal_Lulus' => Yii::t('app', 'Tanggal  Lulus'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getNRP()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(AlumniIntegrasi::className(), ['NRP' => 'NRP']);
    }
}
```

I want to display NamaMahasiswa in table alumniintegrasi. how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a proper getter for the field `NamaMahasiswa`

in your model

change the name of model getter  (aviding case  convention problem for name

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getNrp()
{
    return $this->hasOne(AlumniIntegrasi::className(), ['NRP' => 'NRP']);
}
```

and add the getter simply use the attribute name (based on getter)

```
 /* Getter for NamaMahasiswa */
 public function getNamaMahasiswa() {
    return $this->Nrp->NamaMahasiswa;
 }
```

in the view

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'filterModel' => $searchModel,
      'columns' => [
          ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

          [
          'attribute' => 'namaMahasiswa',
          ],

          'ProgramStudi',
          'Tanggal_Masuk',
          'Tanggal_Lulus',
          ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
      ],
  ]); ?>
```

NB using UpperCamleCase ( Pascal Notation) for database name is not the best choice  .. for database is better use underscore notattion ..